# JSF localized paragraph with embedded links

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

What's the preferred way to embed an outputlink somewhere in the middle of a localized paragraph with JSF 1.2?

Consider a message resource with the following:

```
my.paragraph=If you have questions, visit our {0} for further information
my.paragraph.token.0=help
```

and if you have an outputlink like:

```
<f:outputLink value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pophelp('#facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/help/index.html');">#{messages['my.paragraph.token.0']}</ice:outputLink>
```

If it makes it any easier we are also using SEAM/facelets and icefaces.

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require a specialized form of layout panel component. Assuming there isn't one in your existing component library, you can learn how to write one on blog: [JSF: a custom format panel control for localising component layout](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/jsf-custom-format-panel-control-for.html)